# Change a button dynamically in a table view cell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, macos, uitableview

I have a table where 5 cells are there. In each cell there is a button. I need to change those buttons dynamically on some conditions. How to change the button dynamically in table view.

Comment: are you using storyboards?, are you using static cells?

Comment: What do you mean by change? Change behaviour? Change look? Change text?

Comment: @moonwave99 I need to change the behavior. For Example if it is "call"  and if I click it should change it as "SMS". Once the call is made the next time i can only SMS.

Comment: @tkanzakic am using static cells

Comment: @2vision2 you just want to change it when an action is performed?, if so you can use the sender parameter to apply the changes that you need

Comment: wt do mean dynamically change ??? i cnt get it ?? plaease expalin clearly

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is Write a function which will change the values of the buttons and then you can call that function. After changing button values then use any one of the mentioned method below:

You can use either : `[tableview reloadData];` to reload all the table data.

OR

You can reload particular rows using the following method :

`[tableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: indexPath withRowAnimation:anyKindOfAnimation];`

Answer (score 1):

You can query your table view for all visible cells through `-visibleCells`, get the reference of your button (assuming you have a `UITableViewCell` subclass with a property for the button) and change them.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set tags for each buttons. This can be done by

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//Your code
cell.Button.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.Button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

}

Then you can get the button from this method

```
- (IBAction)buttonClick1:(id)sender {

int tagNo =[sender tag];
UITableViewCell *cellclicked = [self.tblProfileFollowing cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:tagNo inSection:0]];
//Now change the action for the cell
[cellclicked.Button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//Your Code
```

}

You can follow the same steps for  **- (IBAction)buttonClick2:(id)sender**

Now you can track which button was clicked and change the method for that button.

And declare your cell and button **strong**.